Ratio test for sequence convergence
The convergence part of the ratio test for real sequences says, roughly, that if the absolute values of the ratios of a given (non-zero) sequence $a_n$ are, for sufficiently large $n$, bounded below 1, then the given sequence $a_n$ converges to 0, since $a_n$ can be compared to a geometric sequence whose ratio is strictly less than 1.
However, the above scenario does not include the case in which the ratios $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ are all strictly less than 1 but approach as close to 1 as one wants - eg., when their limit superior (or even their limit) is exactly 1.
I would like to have a counterexample in this situation.
More specifically, I would like to see an example of a sequence $a_n$ such that, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1$, the limit (or limsup) of $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ is exactly 1, while $a_n$ does not converge.

The ratio test limit is $1$ for every $p$-series, so pick a value of $p$ such that the ratios are always less than $1$ and the $p$-series does not converge.

The absolute value is convergent, as the sequence $|a_n|$ is non increasing. But for general $a_n$ consider $a_n=(-1)^n(1-n^{-1})$

@Dave: I am familiar with these counterexamples in the case of series. I would like to see a plain sequence though.

What is a "plain sequence"? The $p$-series are about as basic as one can get, probably only less basic than geometric series.

@Ryszard: if my computations are correct, for the "general" $a_n$ you propose, the quantity $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ is not less than 1. Right?

@Dave: "plain sequence" means deal directly with the sequence $a_n$, not consider the series emerging from its partial sums, since it is pedadogically preferable.

not consider the series emerging from its partial sums --- At first I didn't know what you meant, but now I do. For others reading, the following is intended: "not consider a sequence that (more naturally) arises from the partial sums of a non-convergent series".

@Dave: Yes, exactly - thanks for clarifying. This is what I want.

Note, by the way, that for the "divergence part" of the ratio test, there is an easy corresponding counterexample: let $a_n=n$ and note that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|>1$, for all $n$, with the limit of the ratios being exactly 1, while the sequence diverges to infinity. That is, this is a counterexample where the ratios approach 1 from above. My question is to find a counterexample where the ratios approach 1 from below. Pedadogically, this would explain why we need the ratios to be bounded away from 1 (in either case), for the test to work.

My first example was incorrect  Consider $a_n=(-1)^n({1\over 2}+{1\over n})$

This is now fixed and what I asked for. Thanks Ryszard.
